# Can't see modification of model fields in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

When i add or modify fields or model, there are no changes in admin panel after migrate.

Get this issue short time after deploy on server (engine x + g unicorn + django3.0 + sqlite3):

Added some field in models file -> added this field in fields list Admin class (admin file) ->
manage make migrations -> manage migrate, so i get the message of successful migration...but then i see no scheme changes in admin panel. Database is modified and i don't have this problem on local test server.

models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class AdultCatCard(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Name')
    testfield = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50, verbose_name='testfield')
```

admin file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import AdultCatCard
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class CatCardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'testfield']

admin.site.register(AdultCatCard, CatCardAdmin)
```

Comment: Can you provide more details of what's happening, or what is the desired and the current behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, sorry for my heedless question. The issue, which i got, was caused by mess with wsgi configuration. Admin panel works fine with correct g unicorn config file.